# Erratic output in shell script for mysql query

Tags: mysql, bash

I have written a shell script to execute my data base query

```
mysql -uroot -pshruti2 -B -e "use WebNmsDB;select HEADERINDEX from tekelec_meas_headers where CLLI=$clli and IVALSTART>="$ivalstart" and IVALSTART<"$ivalend" and RPTTYPE="$rpttype";" > win.txt
```

But the output in win.txt is

```
/mysql Ver 14.12 Distrib 5.0.44, for unknown-linux-gnu (x86_64) using EditLine wrapper
Copyright (C) 2002 MySQL AB
This is commercial software, and use of this software is governed
by your applicable license agreement with MySQL
Usage: /Tekelec/WebNMS/mysql/bin/mysql [OPTIONS] [database]
```

where is it going wrong?

Comment: we need more detail, please edit your question to include the code before the call to mysql that shows how/what you are setting the variables contained in the query, i.e. `$clli , "$ivalstart"` etc. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Use `'$var'` instead of `"$var"`. You  should only use double quotes to open and close the MYSQL command.

The command will now look like this:

```
mysql -uroot -pshruti2 -B -e "use WebNmsDB;select HEADERINDEX from tekelec_meas_headers where CLLI=$clli and IVALSTART>='$ivalstart' and IVALSTART<'$ivalend' and RPTTYPE='$rpttype'" > win.txt
```

One last thing: If I'm not mistaken, you don't need the last semicolon as it's only used to separate several commands and not to finish them.